# How to load js file on load of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Title>My Test</Title>
<script src="http://someurl.com/test.js"></script>
</Head>
<Body>
This is for test
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Above mentioned is my HTML code. When I right click my page & hit "view source" I can see exact same code.

But what my requirement is, instead of `<script>...</script>` I want actual javascript code from test.js should be displayed when I am hitting "view source".

I tried to put it in iframe, but it didn't worked.

Comment: i didn't get you . do you want to load that script file in your page ?

Comment: Yes! when I will go to view source, code from test.js should be displayed on view source.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is impossible to achieve with HTML and an external JS file.

There is no way to make View Source show anything other than the actual source code of the URL.

If you want to look at the JavaScript source code, then look at the URL for the JavaScript. Most browsers will hyperlink it in View Source to make it easy to do.

---

If you really want the JS to be displayed as part of the source of the HTML document, then you have to make it part of the HTML document. Remove the `src` attribute and copy the contents of the JS file to between the start and end tag of the script element.

Comment: my expectation is what you have said in second part of your answer. Is it possible to achieve by answer of Rahul Desai?

Comment: No. It isn't. I said it isn't in this answer. I said it isn't in comments on his answer.

Answer (score -2):

add a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` section

```
<script src="path/to/test.js"></script>
```